# How can i take the first element of my [[char]]

Tags: haskell

I'm a newbie with `Haskell` and I'm trying to have the first `elem` of my `[[char]]`

I tried this:
(in my main)

```
    tmpList = recomposeNumber (words argss) []
                det = test tmpList
```

`tmpList` is a `[[Char]]`

my `tmpList` is:

```
["12","+","1"]
```

and I try something like that but I don't know how to do

```
test:: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
test [x:xs]  = x
```

and I don't know if its possible but I would like to return an `integer`

I would like to return "12" with the test function and I am lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you want this:

```hs
test :: [[Char]] -> Int
test (x:xs) = read x :: Int -- :: Int is not necessary
```

So, with reference to your attempt, the mistakes are:

- wrong signature: you want to return an `Int`, just use `Int` as the result, not `[[Char]]` (which by the way is exactly the same as `[String]`)
- wrong symbols for pattern matching: you need round brackets, not square brackets
- incomplete implementation: if you want to get an `Int` from a `String`, you need a function that can do that (`read`)

As suggested in a comment, the type annotation `:: Int` is not necessary, since the signature `[[Char]] -> Int` implies it.

Since I was trying to be fast, I tested it in `ghci`, where you cannot just enter a standalone signature, so there I had to use the type annotation, and I forgot to remove it when pasting the code here.

As a side note, you might be interested in [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: N.B. the `:: Int` part is not necessary, because the type signature already has enough information to deduce the type

Comment: in ghci, key-in `:{` and then press Enter; now you can enter your definitions line by line; to finish, key-in `:}` and press Enter. there's also the multi-line mode which you enter by typing `:set +m <Enter>` at the prompt. then you can enter your lines separated by Enter (with no white space at line's end). an extra Enter or some  whitespace at line's end ends the sequence of lines being processed together.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
head tmpList
```

or this:

```
head ["12","+","1"]
```

That will give you the first element of the list.

Comment: Thanks!  i knew head and tail but i wanted to take the n argument :)